# Good way for git to ignore build folders in C++ project?

Tags: git, build, gitignore

I'm currently working on a C++ project and use git for version control.

Now, we're using the git repo folder as the main project folder, so every time a change is pushed, it includes the relevant build folders (`build-ProjectName-Desktop-Debug sorta style folder`)

I'm aware of `gitignore` being a thing, can I somehow tell that to ignore all folders whose name starts with `build-`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use wildcards in your `.gitignore` file.

So for example:

```
build-*
```

Comment: `build-*` will ignore all names (files *and* directories/folders); if you want to limit it to *just* folders, use `build-*/` (trailing slash). Both are correct, they just achieve slightly different goals.